# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException For Loops

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nullpointerexception

I have a problem with the for loop because of the nullpointerexception error.

```
for (int num = 0; num < checkingAcct.getSize(); num++)
```

And the error comes up as:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at application2.Panel.listTransactions(Panel.java:152)
at application2.Application2$Application2a.actionPerformed(Application2.java:84)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:308)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

The for loop is line 152. As for application2 line 84

```
 if (codee == dos)
           Panel.listTransactions(); <-----
```

And then getSize:

```
public int getSize(){
    transSize = transList.size();
    return transSize;
}
```

Based on google findings, NullPointerException means that I didn't initialize something. But I don't know what to intialize. transSize was initialized to 0.

Thank you~

Comment: It looks like `checkingAcct` is the problem. Are you sure you *initialized* it (`CheckingAcct checkingAcct = new CheckingAcct();`), or did you just *declare* it (`CheckingAcct checkingAcct;`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error happening at the for loop, I suspect that your `checkingAcct` is `null`. Make sure you are using the constructor to initialize:

`CheckingAccount checkingAcct = new CheckingAccount();`.

If you're already doing that, make sure that it's not being assigned to null anywhere else in your code.

Comment: I have `Checking checkingAcct = new Checking (balance);` in the coding. But it is under another function. Should it be brought up to main? (since the problem is in a different function)

Comment: If your new is not global, you must make sure that the function that initializes your object runs before the loop that is causing the problem. Otherwise, seeing you you are using it multiple times across methods I would just put it global. BTW, by global I mean you put it inside the class, but not in any method, so not in `main` as you said, but just after `public class Application2 {`, or whatever your class is.